# .net regex match line

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Why does `^.*$` does not match a line in:

> This is some sample text
>
> this is another line
>
> this is the third line

how can I create a regular expression that will match an entire line so that when finding the next match it will return me the next line.

**In other words I will like to have** a regex so that the first match = `This is some sample text` , next match = `this is another line` etc...

Comment: Why don't you simply use `StringReader.ReadLine`?

Comment: This isn't an exact answer to your question, but if you could elaborate on what you are doing there might be a much better non-regex solution for this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`^` and `$` match on the entire input sequence.  You need to use the Multiline Regex option to match individual lines within the text.

```
Regex rgMatchLines = new Regex ( @"^.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) for an explanation of the regex options.  Here's what it says about the Multiline option:

> Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of `^` and `$` so they match at the
> beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the
> beginning and end of the entire string.

Answer (score 4):

use regex options

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable `RegexOptions.Multiline` to make `^` and `$` matches the start and end of line. Otherwise, `^` and `$` will match the start and end of the whole input string.